# Django - huge memory usage on "for" with QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have such QuerySet in Django.

```
j = piosenki.objects.select_related('projekt__postac').distinct().exclude(typ__in=["live", "remix"]).filter(piosenki__plyta__status=1, piosenki__plyta__typ='s')
.extra(select={ 'ocena' : 'dobroc', 'plyta' : 'SELECT plyta_id FROM plyty_piosenki INNER JOIN plyty_plyty ON plyty_plyty.id = plyty_piosenki.plyta_id WHERE piosenka_id = muzyka_piosenki.id AND plyty_plyty.typ = \'s\' ORDER BY plyty_plyty.id DESC LIMIT 1' })
```

When I loop it with for statement and simply just print "id" memory keeps growing until...

```
[1286986.701097] Killed process 4627 (python2.6) total-vm:731872kB, anon-rss:635724kB, file-rss:268kB
[1286986.768701] python2.6: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x201da
[1286986.768705] Pid: 4627, comm: python2.6 Not tainted 2.6.39-gentoo-r2 #1
```

Any suggestions? I know that Django loads results in memory, but Postgres reports size of table around 200 MB, so...

Comment: How large is the table? Also, could you post your django template code for your loop?

Comment: "but Postgres reports size of table around 200 MB, so...", it's simple for i in j: print w.id.

Comment: Are you selecting every row? You also have several joins and an extra, so the joined table could be well over 200MB for some reason. FWIW it looks like it's getting up to 750MB when it dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure you use [db_index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on the fields you do sorting and joining on. Secondly, try [queryset iterators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator):

> For a QuerySet which returns a large number of objects, this often
>   results in better performance and a significant reduction in memory

Comment: Additionally, make sure you have DEBUG=False in your settings.py otherwise it remembers every SQL query you execute (eating RAM).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need model instances or only certain fields returned, use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)/[values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to select only a subset of the fields the model has and not initializing a model instance for every result.